# Not able to fetch the value of the array element from curl call in php

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl call in php to get the response from one of the REST endpoint. The following is the code that will execute the curl call and get the result into array `$result_array`

```
$post_url = 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/realm-nextcloud/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect';
        $curl = curl_init($post_url);
        $fields = array(
                        'client_id' => "test",
                        'client_secret' => "*****-*****",
                        'token_type_hint' => "access_token",
                        'token' => "kjfhakf"
                        );
        //Url-ify the data to prepare for the post request
        $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
        //Open the connection   
        $ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result_array = json_decode($result,true);
var_dump($result_array);
```

The var_dump of the array `$result_array` gives the following output:

```
array(1) {
  ["active"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Although, I want to extract the value of the "active" field in the array, but I can't seem to get it with `$result_array[0] or $result_array['active']`.

Also, if I use `var_dump($result_array["active"])` I will get the output as `bool(false)` but `echo $result_array["active"]`doesn't print anything ?

How to get the value of the field `echo $result_array["active"]` as `false` in a string?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I won't be able to print out the boolean value with echo (not sure if I can print it by any other method), but the value of the field can be tested with the following code and the result can be set in the form of the string to a variable using `if-else`.

```
    $result_boolean = $result_json["active"];
    if($result_boolen)
    {
            $val = "TRUE";
            echo $val;
    }
    else
    {
            $val = "FALSE";
            echo $val;
    }
```